# How do I get italic sans-serif in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, italic, sans-serif

I have a paper in which I originally used mathit, bold mathit, mathcal and bold mathcal to distinguish various types of entities. Reviewing the paper on-screen it appears that `\mathit{C}` and `\mathcal{C}` are very similar in appearance. My first thought was to use sans-serif in place of the default font, but LaTeX doesn't let you combine `\mathit` and `\mathsf`.

The pdflatex font tables are close to full, and `XeTeX` is not an option since I can't control the compilation process of `arXiv` or other publishers. Is there a way to get italic sans-serif without loading additional fonts, and is there an alternative way to distinguish the entities for which I currently use bold, default, calligraphic and bold calligraphic. Note: I don't load bold fonts; I use `\bm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{cref}
\showlabels{crefrange}

\begin{document}

 $C$ default

 $\mathit C$ mathit

 $\mathcal C$ mathcal

 $\mathsf{C}$ mathsf

 $\bm C$ bm default

 $\bm{\mathcal{C}}$ bm mathcal

 $\bm{\mathit{\mathsf{C}}}$ bm mathit mathsf

\end{document}
```

I attempted to resolve this based on a suggestion by egreg, but the weight of the italic sans-serif was heavier than the weight of normal sans-serif. After I fixed a typo it worked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{cref}
\showlabels{crefrange}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbd}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfbd}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{normal}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\itdefault}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbdit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfbdit}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\itdefault}

\begin{document}

 $C$ default

 $\mathit C$ mathit

 $\mathcal C$ mathcal

 $\mathsf{C}$ mathsf

$\mathsfbd{C}$ mathsfbd

$\mathsfbdit{C}$ mathsfbdit

$\mathsfit{C}$ mathsfit

 $\bm C$ bm default

 $\bm{\mathcal{C}}$ bm mathcal

 $\bm{\mathit{\mathsf{C}}}$ bm mathit mathsf

$\bm{\mathsf{C}}$ bm mathsf

$\bm{\mathsfbd{C}}$ bm mathsfbd

$\bm{\mathsfit{C}}$ bm mathsfit

$\bm{\mathsfbdit{C}}$ bm mathsfbdit

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Math alphabets commands such as `\mathit` and `\mathsf` are not “cumulative”. You have to allocate a specific math alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % not needed if not using Computer Modern

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\mddefault}{\sldefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\sldefault}

\begin{document}

$C$ default

$\mathit{C}$ mathit

$\mathcal{C}$ mathcal

$\mathsf{C}$ mathsf

$\mathsfit{C}$ mathsfit

$\bm{C}$ bm default

$\bm{\mathcal{C}}$ bm mathcal

$\bm{\mathsf{C}}$ bm mathsf

$\bm{\mathsfit{C}}$ bm mathsfit

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why {bold}? I'm looking for normal weight italic sns-serif unless I apply BM to it. Possibly I should have declarations for mathsift and mathsfitbd and skip the bm. What would that look like? Thanks.

Comment: @shmuel Don't you get medium weight sans serif italic with `\mathsfit{C}` and bold sans serif italic with `\bm{\mathsfit{C}}`?

Comment: Yes, I get medium weight sans serif italic with `\mathsfit{C}`, but I want the same weight as `\mathsf(C)`. I tried `\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{normal}{T1}{\sfdefault}{}{\itdefault}`, but that still gave me medium weight. I've updated my MWE to show the failed attempt.

Comment: @shmuel I don't understand: with `\mathsf{C}` and `\mathsfit{C}` the weight is exactly the same.

Comment: All I know is that when I compile the MWE with pdflatex, the `\mathsf{C}` is lighter than the `\mathsfit{C}`. I can send you, e.g., the PDF file, if that would help.

Comment: I just spotted a typo. after correcting it I got normal weight for `\mathsfit{C}`. Thanks.

Comment: This does not work anymore when using TeX Live 2020 (tested on overleaf). Apparently `\bfdefault` changed from `bx` to `b`. `\bfdefault` can be replaced with `bx` to make this work again in newer versions of TeX Live.

Comment: @MrTsjolder Add `\usepackage{fix-cm}`, which is a good thing to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether you are only seeking text characters, you could use the math `\text` command:

```
  \[ \text{\sffamily\itshape  ABC abc}\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `unicode-math`, etc. `\symsfit`.  (You might also be able to use `\mathsfit`, but that will by default get you a text font.) This requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

In PDFTeX, `isomath` will give you a `\mathsfit` alphabet when passing the option OMLmathsfit, i.e. `\usepackage[OMLmathsfit]{isomath}`.