# Several lines in a bracket

Tags: equations, brackets

Can someone display a method to write something like this in latex?
[image]

Comment: Welcome! You can use an array for that: `\left[\begin{array}{l} stuff\\ stuff\\ stuff \end{array}\right]`. There are many variations of that.

Comment: @arman was my answer of any help

Answer (score 1):

Here there is the closer screenshot of the user *@arman haghighi*. For the italic sans-serif in math-mode it is important to see this link: [How do I get italic sans-serif in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434391/how-do-i-get-italic-sans-serif-in-math-mode)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[\mathrm{Pr}\left[\begin{array}{l}
\mathsf{pp}, A_0\in\mathbb{G}\overset{\$}{\leftarrow}\textbf{\textit{Setup}}(\lambda)\\ 
A(x,w_x,w_y,u_x)\overset{\$}{\leftarrow}\mathcal{A}(\mathsf{pp},A_0)\\
\textbf{\textit{VerMem}}(A,x,w^{t}_{x})\wedge \textbf{\textit{VernotMem}}(A,x,u^{t}_{x})\end{array}\right]=\mathsf{negl}(\lambda)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \[
    X(m,n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        x(n), & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq 1\\
        x(n-1), & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq 1\\
        x(n-1), & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq 1
        \end{array}\right\} = xy
  \]
\end{document}
```

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240870/197451

**OR**

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, 
suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi.
\begin{equation}
\bar{P}= 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (M.center),% center with respect to the matrix center
        every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1ex},%tighter delimiter spacing
        every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-1ex}]
\matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]} 
        ]{ 
                              0.3 & 0.1 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                              0.2 & 0.1 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                              0.3 & 0.4 & 0.3 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                              0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                              0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.7 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
                              0.0 & 0.4 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
                              0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1 & 0.0 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0.5 \\
};
\node[anchor=south east] (cornernode) at (M-1-1.north west) {state}; %Position this more 
                                                                     %precisely if desired
\foreach[count=\xi] \x in {1,2,4,3,6,5,7}{ %\xi is the counter \x is the value
\node (M-\xi-0) at (cornernode |- M-\xi-1) {\x}; %Gets the left most column
\node (M-0-\xi) at (cornernode -| M-1-\xi) {\x}; % Gets the top row 
}
\draw[decoration=brace,decorate,blue] (M-0-1.north west) -- (M-0-3.north east)%
 node[midway,above] {$S_1$};
\draw[decoration=brace,decorate,blue] (M-0-4.north west) -- (M-0-5.north east)%
 node[midway,above] {$S_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[How can I add size of Tikz drawing into size of equation? (PART 2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48288/how-can-i-add-size-of-tikz-drawing-into-size-of-equation-part-2/48289#48289)