# draw circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, draw, circuits

[image]

[image]

Hello friends, could you helpme? I need to draw this circuits but I dont know, thanks for your help.

Comment: Well what have you tried? Maybe provide some MWE?

Comment: My personal suggestion is to go through (in the sense: read *and* try) the first tutorial in the Ti*k*Z manual and then the tutorials in circuitikz manual. You need to dedicate a few hours to it, but it's absolutely usefuls if you are serious about using circuitikz.

Comment: Except possibly the ocirc node, you don't need circuitiks for this.

Comment: Any news? You got three answers ... It is time to decide which one of them the best fulfil your expectation and accept it then (by clicking check mark at top left side of selected answer). As I see, so far you have not accepted any of the answers to your questions. By this you tell us, that no one your question is not solved. Is this true?

Comment: For all, thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0)       to [short,o-] ++ (1,0) node[right] (p) {$p$}
        (p.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] (q) {$q$}
        (q.east)    to [short,-o] ++ (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0)   to [short,o-] ++ (1,0) coordinate (a)
        (a) |- ++ (1, 0.5) node[right] (p) {$p$}
        (p.east) -| ++ (1,-0.5) coordinate (b) 
        (b) to [short,-o] ++ (1,0)
        (a) |- ++ (1,-0.5) node[right] (q) {$q$}
        (q) -| (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Considered is @rmano comment.

Comment: NIce, +1, --- and I think you found a bug in `circuitikz`, because your code (which is ok) gives a warning in newer Ti*k*Z

Comment: @Rmano, you are right. Since warning is somewhere on the middle of ˙`.log` file, I didn't notice it.. It complain about node coordinates when construct `to [short,-o] ` is used. bu not at `--` : `Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. D
id you specify a point identical to the center of node ``q''? on input line 9.` Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's the bug ;-) see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/562.

Comment: Anyway, if you want that the branch of the second diagram become symmetrical, you should use ` (p.east) -| ++ (1,-0.5) coordinate (b)` (relative coordinates are computed from the center of the node even if then the border anchor is used).

Comment: @Rmano, you are right. This should be used at relative coordinates. Using it, also warning disappear. So there is no bug?

Comment: No, it's still a bug.You should be able to use a node name before the `to` and have the border anchor automatically used. Like in `\node[draw](a) at(0,0) {A}; \node[draw](b) at(1,2) {B}; \draw (a) to[R] (b);`

Comment: You might want to render node labels to italicized math sans serif similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434391/how-do-i-get-italic-sans-serif-in-math-mode

Comment: @MarkA.Bromuela, ah, you see such fonts on image of OP question :-).  Well, it not give any information about document where will be this image. For example, in beamer, such fonts are defaul.t  Anyway, I can add sans serif math font, but after some respond of OP.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way of doing the same. It's mostly `tikz`. The node shape `node[ocirc]{}` from `circuitikz` is used.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0)node[ocirc]{} 
-- node[fill=white]{$p$} ++(2,0)
-- node[fill=white]{$q$} ++(2,0)node[ocirc]{}

(0,-2)node[ocirc]{} 
-| ++(1,0.5) 
-- node[fill=white]{$p$} ++(2,0) 
|- ++(1,-0.5)node[ocirc]{}
-| ++(-1,-0.5) 
-- node[fill=white]{$q$} ++(-2,0)
-- ++(0,0.5)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]